# Save for web feature in Photoshop for image size reduction

Tags: image, photoshop

Save for web feature in Photoshop for image size reduction, would this be the simplest way for a beginner (like myself) to try and save on (some) loading time.

I am using images for my menu buttons, background, header, post page, etc etc

I have only just found this save for web feature and I was wondering does it really help in image size or does it not make that much difference.

Is there any other option?

(website for reference: www.kizzieskorner.com)

PS: if you mark my question down please could you give an explanation why so I know what not to do next time - as I am new to these question forums too!

Comment: Try posting this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: never heard of those sites until now - so thankyou!

Comment: @Kizzie86 It makes a huge difference and you should always use it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reductions in size will help of course. I would actually recommend looking at other image optimising tools.

If you are on a mac there is ImageOptim which is part of my regular workflow now. There is also an optimiser within CodeKit.

This site has a whole host of others listed too and might give you a bit more information on the subject.

http://devstand.com/apps/compress-images-apps/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much edwardgd looks like I have some reading to do - thanks for your time and help!